# How can Edge pop up a YouTube tab that I've got open in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, microsoft-edge, cross-browser

I use a number of browsers. One reason is that it (tries) to keep their caches separate. Naïve, I know - but it (mostly) works. However, when it *doesn't*, I'm curious why.

So, I'm watching a YouTube video in Chrome, and then decide to Bing for some fact using Edge. I open Edge as a new instance (no previous ones extant) and start to type the desired URL - and then notice that there's already an *additional* tab with the YouTube logo. When I click on it, it is literally the same video as what I'm watching in Chrome.

It's repeatable, so not a fluke. This may already be a 'thing', but I don't watch this sort of intrusion - so apologies for rearing a dead horse. My curiosity is piqued by the idea that the two browsers are supposed to be independent, yet obviously aren't. Can anyone explain this effect?

Comment: Is it repeatable with any video you play in Chrome, or a specific video? As you "knew" they are indeed separate so it's quite odd what you describe. Any possibility of doing a screen recording of how this happens? (Record the whole screen showing both browsers open with no open tabs except one new tab > Go to YouTube in Chrome and watch a video and then check Edge if it has the video.)

Comment: As far as I have observed it's completely repeatable. I'll try to replicate in a recording.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "feature". Edge imports browser data from competitors on each launch – including bookmarks and open tabs. You can disable it in "Settings > Profiles > Import".

Comment: On each launch it does that? In Settings > Profiles > Import I don't see anything mentioned about "on each launch" and no setting to disable. And from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-s-imported-to-microsoft-edge-ab7d9fa1-4586-23ce-8116-e46f44987ac2 it also seems to be only manually import or on "first" open (and even then it prompts you.)

Comment: Might be mistaken as to where it's supposed to be turned on/off, but I distinctly remember [a recent update](https://winbuzzer.com/2022/05/30/microsoft-edge-to-pull-data-from-chrome-on-every-launch-xcxwbn/) where the first-time dialog started asking me about "periodically" re-importing the data.

Comment: Oh, that was for a "Canary build". Doesn't seem like this made it into Release (or Beta) so far. But maybe the OP has Edge Canary...